# How to wait for ES indexing to finish in Rspec and Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, elasticsearch, tire

How to avoid using `sleep 1` in that example for wait until ES indexing will be finished?

```
describe Question do
  before do
    create :question, content: "Some test question",
                      app: @app
    create :question, content: "Some other question",
                      app: @app
    sleep 1
  end

  it_behaves_like "search results found" do
    let(:query) { "Some" }
    let(:results) { ["Some test question", "Some other question"] }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make a call to the 'refresh' API endpoint.  If you're using Tire and the ActiveModel integration feature, it would be:

```
Question.tire.index.refresh
```

Alternatively you can use curl to hit the endpoint directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `refresh` on the index and that will cause it to rebuild:

`Question.index.refresh`